# Using VLookup in VBA type mismatch error

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to figure out how to use vlookups in vba.

```
Function Check_NPI_NUM(pracno As String, npi As String) As String
   Dim tempRange As Range
   Set tempRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tempSheet").Columns("C:D")

   Dim fixedPracno As Variant
   'fixed pracno will look like this "$C$64941"
   fixedPracno = Replace(pracno, "H", "C")

   If (npi = "0") Then
    Check_NPI_NUM = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(fixedPracno, tempRange, 2, False), "0")
   Else
    Check_NPI_NUM = npi
   End If
End Function
```

I think my problem is the second part of the lookup to another sheet. I get a mismatch type error and I can't figure out why. If it is the first part of the lookup can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a much better idea to use `Find` and `Offset` rather than `VLookup` in VBA. Offset by one column to replicate `2,0)` in `VLOOKUP`. Something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim tableArray As Range, found As Range

    Set tableArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000")

    Set found = tableArray.Find(what:="someValue", lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox found.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this is great! Thanks so much, fit much better in my code and it looks neater.

Comment: @SteveG, no problem. Happy to help